# Scala return "partial" class which must be mixed-in with trait later

Tags: scala, types, traits, scala-macros

I have a trait

```
trait DataDef {
    def getDataSource: java.sql.DataSource
}
```

And then several other traits, which inherit this trait, for example

```
trait Postgres extends DataDef {
      // Postgres implementation
}
```

and,

```
trait MySql extends DataDef {
     // For My SQL
}
```

And another abstract class (and I can convert it to trait, if required)

```
abstract class Strategy[T](strategyType: String) {
    self: DataDef =>

    def lookup(): Stream[T] = {
         // use self.getDataSource and strategyType here
    }
}
```

This way I can keep the code separate for Strategy and Data. For example,

```
class StrategyA extends Strategy[Int]("typeA") {
    self: DataDef =>
    // implementation of this strategy
}
```

Now, what I want to do is wire these two together so that when user passes certain strategyType and DataDef type, I can pass the relevant object. What I have so far is:

```
class getStrategy(strategyType: String, dataType: String) {
    strategyType match {
         case "typeA" => 
            dataType match {
                 case "postgres" => return StrategyA with Postgres
                 case "mysql" => return StrategyA with MySql
            }
         case "typeB" => 
            dataType match {
                 case "postgres" => return StrategyB with Postgres
                 case "mysql" => return StrategyB with MySql
            }
    }
}
```

The issue is there is so much of code being repeated and it does not look like and elegant solution. I should be able to return `Postgres`, `MySql` just once, and should not need to repeat the code over and over.

I want something like:

```
 def getStrategy(strategyType: String) {
      // return Strategy here, like new StrategyA
 }

 def getDataDef(dataType: String) {
     // return DataDef here 
 }
```

And then I should be able to mix it, like so:

```
 getStrategy(strategyType) with getDataDef(dataType)
```

I have looked into macros and they look promising, but very complicated. I was wondering if there is any other, simpler way of achieving what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not literally what you want: `with` lives in the type world, not in the value world, and types can't be returned from methods.

But if you go with composition over inheritance you can do e.g.

```
abstract class Strategy[T](strategyType: String, self: DataDef) {
    // optional
    // import self._

    def lookup(): Stream[T] = {
         // use self.getDataSource and strategyType here
    }
}

class StrategyA(self: DataDef) extends Strategy[Int]("typeA", self) {
    // implementation of this strategy
}

def getStrategy(strategyType: String): DataDef => Strategy {
     // return e.g. new StrategyA(_)
}

def getDataDef(dataType: String) {
    // return DataDef here 
}
```

and then

```
getStrategy(strategyType)(getDataDef(dataType))
```

Comment: Thank you! This workaround worked great. I just changed `abstract class Strategy[T](strategyType: String, self: DataDef)` to `abstract class Strategy[T](strategyType: String)(self: D forSome {type D <: DataDef})`. Do you think it has any issues?

Comment: Rather, I don't see any benefit (from the existential type, not from two parameter lists): you already can pass any subtype of `DataDef`, you can't access `D` inside `Strategy`. Just a more complicated way to write it.